# PresentModalViewController with the same animation as push view in a navigation controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

Is it possible to use the PresentModalViewController with the same animation that is shown when using the "pushViewController" method of a navigation controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it can't move horizontally. And what's more, when you use `presentModalViewController:animated:`, the previous view will disappear(be blank). But you can do like this(add your desired view to the top of your window):

```
UIViewController *modalViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[modalViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(320.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
[modalViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window addSubview:modalViewController.view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     [modalViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
                 }
                 completion:nil];

[modalViewController release];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `UIStoryboardSegue` instead of the approved answer above. It would seem that it's the proper way to achieve the effect and view hierarchy.

It can be used in conjunction with  `presentModalViewController:animated:` as noted at the end of the documentation under "perform".

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html